# How do you call a function within a FreeMarker macro?

Tags: freemarker

Is there a way to call a function within a Freemarker macro?
Example of what I am trying to do:

```
<#function foo>
  <return "hello">
</#function>

<#macro fooMacro>
  ${foo()}    
</#macro>

<@fooMacro> <#-- This doesn't work for me
                 "The "foo()" has evaluated to null or missing" -->
```

Similarly, is there a way to pass the output of a function into a param of a macro? Like:

```
<#macro fooMacro p1>
   ${p1}
</#macro>

<@fooMacro p1=foo()/> <!-- Also doesn't seem to work for me -->
```

Comment: Actually upon further investigation of my project, my problem might be with the function itself returning invalid value... If these two actions are possible perhaps it's a problem with my project code.

Comment: Ugh the problem with this was I was missing '#' on the return tag. So it was returning the null/missing error each time when I called the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: both are possible, just change

```
<return "hello">  ==>  <#return "hello">
```